# General term of the sequence related question

Tags: sequences-and-series

> What is general term of the following sequence?
>   
> $n = 2, \; 3, .... 29, \; 30 ...\ $
>   $f(n) = 2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,9,10,10,10,11,12,12,12,13,14,14,14,15,16...$

I don't have any idea

Comment: $f(3n-1)=f(3n)=2n,f(3n+1)=2n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean
$$f(n) = 2, \; 2, \; 3, \; 4, \; 4, \;5,\;6,\;6,\;7,\;8,\;8,\;9\color{red}{,}\;10,\;10,\;11,\;12,\;12,\;13,\;14,\;14,\;15,\;16,\;16\color{red}{,}\;17,\;18,\;18,\;19,\;20,\;20$$
then $$f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{2n+2}{3}\right\rfloor$$
should be what you want.